# Python Dictionary, same strings goes into a key

Tags: python, dictionary

Python newbie here.

I have a file that contains many strings. Some of these strings have the same ID. I would like to add those ID's into one single key.

The data, that would come from a file, would look like:

```
    1234, Random User, first data
    2345, Another User, random data
    1234, Random User, different data
```

How would I put the first and third string into the same key of a dictionary.

```
    1234: {[1234, Random User, first data], [1234, Random User, different data]}
    2345: {[2345, Another User, random data]}
```

Something like that is what I would like.

From that newly created dictionary, how would I extract just part of the data such as I want to print only the users name or the data.

Comment: regex the keys and use `defaultdict` from `collections` module.

Comment: Are both `Random User` for `first data` and `Random User` for `different data` the same?
Is that really how you want the data to be presented? Please give a description of what you intend the data to be used like also to prevent the [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: yes, Random User are the same user because they have the same ID(1234). 
The data, for example, would be 2 ints that I would add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)

for line in open('myfile.txt'):
    key = line.split(",", 1)[0]
    res[key].append(line)
```